# Map $\operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V^*) \longrightarrow K^{q}$ defined by $q$ points in $\operatorname{Sym}^p(V)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

**EDIT** : I have edited the question and made it more specific with respect to the kind of answer I expect.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $K$-vector space and let $x_1, \dotsc, x_q \in V$ be $q$ points, no two of them being collinear. It is well-known that for $m \geq q-1$, the evaluation map defined by $(x_1, \dotsc, x_q)$:
$$ \operatorname{Sym}^m(V^*) \longrightarrow K^q$$
is surjective. (The argument goes as follows : since no two of the $x_i$ are collinear, for all $i \neq j$, there exists a linear form on $V$, say $f_{i,j}$ such that $f_{i,j}(x_i) =1$ and $f_{i,j}(x_j) = 0$. Then consider $g_i = \prod_{j \neq i} f_{i,j} \in \operatorname{Sym}^{q-1}(V^*)$ for all $i \in \{1, \dotsc, q\}$.)

I am interested in the following generalization. Let $p \geq 1$ and $x_1, \dotsc, x_q \in \operatorname{Sym}^p(V)$. For all $m \geq 1$, consider the map:
$$\Phi_m : \operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V^*) \rightarrow K^q$$
given by the composition of the natural inclusion $\operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V^*) \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Sym}^{m}\left( \operatorname{Sym}^p(V^*) \right)$ with the evaluation map $\operatorname{Sym}^{m}\left( \operatorname{Sym}^p(V^*) \right) \rightarrow K^q$ defined by the $x_i$.

**Question** : I know that for $m\gg0$ the map $\Phi_m$ is surjective but my argument (see below) is rather intricate. I would like to know if there is a relatively elementary proof (for instance based on representation theory) of the surjectivity of $\Phi_m$ for $m\gg>0$ which does **not** use the following fact:

*Let $P_1, \ldots, P_q$ be homogeneous polynomial of degree $p$, no two of them being collinear. Then, for $m\gg0$ the family $\left\{P_1^m, \ldots, P_q^m \right\}$ is free in $\operatorname{Sym}^{pm}(V^*)$.*

(I am ok to assume the field has zero characteristic).

**Sketch of an intricate proof** : Let $v_m : \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^p(V)) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^m(\operatorname{Sym}^{p}(V)))$ be the $m$-th Veronese embedding and let $q : \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^m(\operatorname{Sym}^{p}(V))) \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V))$ induced by the quotient map $\operatorname{Sym}^{m}(\operatorname{Sym}^{p}(V)) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V)$. Let $f_m$ be the composition $q \circ v_m$:
$$f_m : \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^p(V)) \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V)).$$
The map sends a point $P \in \operatorname{Sym}^p(V)$ (which is seen as an homogeneous polynomial of degree $p$ on $V^*$) to the polynomial $P^m \in \operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V)$. Let $P_1, \ldots, P_q \in \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^p(V))$ be $q$ distinct points. We denote by $J$ the ideal sheaf of the reduced scheme $\{f(P_1), \ldots, f(P_q) \}$. We then have an exact sequence:
$$0 \longrightarrow I \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V))} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{f(P_1), \ldots, f(P_q)} \longrightarrow 0.$$
Twisting this exact sequence by $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V))}(1)$ and taking cohomology, we get an exact sequence:
$$ 0 \longrightarrow H^0(I(1)) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V^*) \longrightarrow K^{q} \longrightarrow H^1(I(1)) \longrightarrow 0,$$
where the map $\operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V^*) \longrightarrow K^{k}$ is the map $\Phi_m$ defined above as the composition of the natural inclusion $\operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V^*) \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Sym}^{m}\left( \operatorname{Sym}^p(V^*) \right)$ with the evaluation map $\operatorname{Sym}^{m}\left( \operatorname{Sym}^p(V^*) \right) \rightarrow K^q$ defined by the $P_i$.

It is clear that $H^0(I(1))$ is the space of hyperplanes that contains the scheme $\{f(P_1),\ldots, f(P_q) \}$. Using the [multivariate case of the MasonStother's Theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.0434v3) (I thank Zach Teitler for this reference) and the first answer in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395657/are-large-powers-of-polynomials-linearly-independent), we find that for $m\gg 0$:
$$ \dim H^0(I(1)) = \dim \operatorname{Sym}^{mp}(V^*) - q.$$
We thus get $H^1(I(1)) = 0$ and the map $\Phi_m$ is surjective.

Comment: Is that map the same thing as the apolarity pairing, with the $m$th power of the $x_i$? That is, say $q=1$, and $F$ is an $mp$-form; the value of $\Phi(F)$ is, then, the apolar pairing of $F$ with $x^m$?

Comment: @ZachTeitler : it's not unlikely, but I don't know how that could be proved.

Comment: A wild speculation: Might it be possible to give a very explicit description of the center of this projection, and show that all its points have border rank strictly greater than $q$ (I.e., don't lie in $q$th secant variety of the Veronese) for sufficiently large $m$? Then every linear combination of the $v_m(x_i)$s, as they lie within the secant variety, is outside the kernel of the projection. So there can't be any linear relations among the $x_i^m$s. Does it sound plausible? But it seems difficult to describe the projection's center well enough to bound the rank of all its points...