# If some powers of polynomials are linearly independent, does it imply higher powers are also independent?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $P_1,\dotsc,P_k$ be polynomials. Assume they are pairwise non-proportional (i.e., any two of them are linearly independent). Suppose $N$ is a power such that $P_1^N,\dotsc,P_k^N$ are linearly independent. Does it follow that $P_1^M,\dotsc,P_k^M$ are linearly independent for all $M \geq N$? Of course $M = N+1$ is sufficient.

The question [Are large powers of polynomials linearly independent?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/395657/) concerns showing that there exists an $N$ giving independence. The [first answer to that question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/395664/) shows that independence holds for all sufficiently large $N$. But *a priori* there might be some gaps after the first such $N$.

I am mostly interested in the case of multivariate homogeneous polynomials all of the same degree, but other cases are good too (univariate, or inhomogeneous or mixed degrees). It would be nice to have an answer over an arbitrary field, but if it helps to assume characteristic $0$ or the complex numbers then that's fine.

The answer is positive if the polynomials are homogeneous of degree $1$, i.e., linear forms. Very briefly: Let $Q_i$ be the point whose coordinates are the coefficients of the linear form $P_i$. The $P_i^M$ are linearly independent if and only if for each $i$ there's a hyperplane (in the space of degree $M$ forms) that contains all the $P_j^M$ for $j \neq i$, but not $P_i^M$; equivalently, for each $i$ there's a degree $M$ form (on the original space) that vanishes at all $Q_j$ for $j \neq i$, but not at $Q_i$; and if this holds for some degree $N$, then it also holds for $N+1$, and all $M \geq N$. (Here I am using the following identification: let $F \in \operatorname{Sym}^M(V)$. Let $L_F$ be the corresponding linear form on $\operatorname{Sym}^M(V^*)$. If we're careful about binomial coefficients, then $L_F(P_i^M) = M! F(Q_i)$.)

I really don't know the answer (let alone how to prove it). My intuition is that the answer is positive (linear independence of $N$th powers does imply linear independence of the $(N+1)$st powers) but that is only a hunch.

Comment: Well, it wasn't as interesting a question as I thought it might be, but still, I want to briefly add an easier argument for the linear case: if the $\ell_i^{N+1}$ are linearly dependent then differentiate...

Comment: @ZT : just to be sure, the first answer you are refering to only proves the result in the univariate case, right? We still don't know if the result is true in the multivariate case?

Comment: @Libli: That first answer works for multivariable polynomials, using a multivariate generalization of Mason-Stothers, see for example Theorem 1.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.0434v3. (I am still reading, but I think the main idea of the generalization to multivariate case is simply to make a general substitution $x_i = a_i t + b_i$ to reduce to univariate.)

Comment: Well, sorry, although the author mentions those general substitutions, it was incorrect to describe that as the main idea --- instead the author has other (nicer) ideas about how to run the proof.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No for $N=1$ and $M=2$. For example $a^2+b^2, a^2-b^2, $ and $ab$ are linearly independent but $(a^2+b^2)^2 - (a^2-b^2)^2 =4 (ab)^2$.

Comment: Oh for goodness's sake, how could I not think of this. Thank you.

Comment: @ZachTeitler More generally for small $M$ the varieties of solutions to a given linear equation in the $M$th powers of variables are unirational. Using this you can find solutions in homogeneous polynomials that are generic in the sense that they don't satisfy any other polynomial equations, which prevents them from being linearly dependent for any lesser power $N$. In the range when the hypersurfaces are Fano you can do something similar with one-variable or homogeneous two-variable solutions. Only for M outside the Fano range might such a statement be true.